# É possível usar if-modified-since com “304 not modified” sem PHP

Tags: apache, htaccess

Me baseando nesta solução usada [nesta resposta no SO-en](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1583753/1518921)
eu criei um .htaccess e um PHP script

.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP:if-modified-since} .
RewriteCond %{HTTP:if-none-match} .
RewriteRule . not_modified.php [L]
```

not_modified.php:

```
<?php
if (isset($_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL'])) {
    $file = $_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL'];
} else if (isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) {
    $file = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
}

$last_modified_time = filemtime($file); 
$etag = md5_file($file);

header('Last-Modified: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', $last_modified_time) . ' GMT'); 

if (
    strtotime($_SERVER['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE']) === $last_modified_time ||
    trim($_SERVER['HTTP_IF_NONE_MATCH']) === $etag
) {
    if (isset($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'])) {
        header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] . ' 304 Not Modified');
    } else {
        header('HTTP/1.0 304 Not Modified');
    }
}
```

O script verifica se houve mudanças no arquivo e se não houver então ele envia o código 304 para a resposta do cliente.

A minha questão é a seguinte, é possível fazer isto sem o uso do PHP, ou seja usando somente `.htaccess`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Para usar [`304 Not Modified`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3.5) para arquivos estáticos será necessário usar o modulo `mod_expires` e "manipular" a regra do `FileETag`:

1. [mod_expires](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_expires.html): Gera os headers HTTP `Expires` e `Cache-Control` de acordo com critérios definidos pelo usuário
2. [FileETag Directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#fileetag)

### mod_expires

Este módulo é necessário para gerar cache e usar o `304 Not Modified`, este módulo trabalha o [`if-modified-since`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.25) e o [`if-none-match`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.26). Um exemplo simples para definir o cache em imagens:

```apacheconf
 #Cache de 1 mês a partir da data de acesso do arquivo
<FilesMatch "\.(?i:ico|gif|jpe?g|png|css|js|svg)$">
   ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 mouth"
</FilesMatch>
```

Note que o cache é gerado a partir da data de acesso da imagem.

### FileETag Directive

Quando usamos Etag ao invés de `if-modified-since` ele as vezes não trabalha de maneira esperada, ou seja ignora que não "houve modificações" e envia o arquivo novamente para a resposta do cliente. Além disto também de acordo com o ["Yahoo! Performance Rules - EN"](https://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#etags), desabilitar os `ETags` podem fazer o carregamento das páginas serem mais rápidos, diminuindo o carregamento do servidor e reduzindo o tamanho da banda se o seu website estiver em múltiplos servidores.

### Exemplo

Um exemplo completo do `.htaccess`, note que não foi necessário usar o `mod_rewrite`:

```apacheconf
# Trabalha o if-modified-since com arquivos de estáticos, como images, js, css, etc
<FilesMatch "\.(?i:ico|gif|jpe?g|png|css|js|svg)$">
    # Cache para um mês
    <IfModule mod_expires.c>
        ExpiresActive On
        ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 mouth"
    </IfModule>
    
    # Remove Etag para previnir o uso do mesmo
    # Pois iremos trabalhar com if-modified-since e last-modifed
    FileETag None
</FilesMatch>
```

Leia também sobre:

- [`if-modified-since`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.25)
- [`if-none-match`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.26)

Comment: Uma dúvida, como foi especificado os 30 dias, se o arquivo for alterado antes desse prazo.. ele continuará usar do cache?

Comment: Sim @Elaine se o arquivo salvo no cache do computador/navegador da pessoa tiver a mesma data de *ultima alteração* então o servidor não envia o arquivo, ele emite apenas o 304 pra resposta e o navegador gera um novo cache com mais 30 dias por exemplo.

Comment: Fiquei um pouco confusa. Se esse arquivo do lado do servidor for alterado eu ficarei com um arquivo obsoleto nos próximos acessos ao site ou será carregada a nova cópia?

Comment: @Elaine será carregado quando o cache expirar, então isto vai do tipo de arquivo, você pode criar um `.htaccess` pra cada pasta, se é uma pasta que tem o conteúdo que altera com muita frequência então faça um tempo de cache menor, se for uma pasta que raramente o conteúdo é alterado faça um cache maior.