# Qual o tempo médio de cache para arquivos estáticos?

Tags: desempenho, cache

Qual o tempo médio de expiração de cache para arquivos estáticos pouco atualizados? Existem técnicas ou recomendações que possam me ajudar na hora de determinar o tempo de expiração?

Um exemplo seria:

```
www.apple.com/scripts/libs/
www.apple.com/css/libs/
```

Quero todos os arquivos que estão dentro do diretório `/libs`
com um tempo de expiração maior para melhorar o desempenho do meu site.

Alguma dica ou referência?

Comment: Apache? Se sim, tente isto: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/44178/3635

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assumindo que você está usando um servidor apache, pode consultar o Caching Guide ([link](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/caching.html)), onde são encontradas algumas recomendações, como esta:

```
The default expiry period for cached entities is one hour, however this
can be easily over-ridden by using the CacheDefaultExpire directive. 
This default is only used when the original source of the content does not
specify an expire time or time of last modification.
```

Ou seja, você pode sobrescrever a recomendação, mas deve estar atento aos arquivos que você vai determinar uma expiração maior - e analisar se o motivo vale a pena, caso contrário, você pode comprometer desempenho. Na documentação citada, existe uma parte que fala **'What Can Be Cashed?'**, onde você pode consultar maiores detalhes sobre o que você vai guardar por mais tempo.

Você também deve levar em conta o `MCacheMaxObjectCount` ([link](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_mem_cache.html#mcachemaxobjectcount)), que determina o número de elementos que você vai armazenar em cash. Parece não fazer sentido, mas no momento que você vai determinar tempos médios diferentes para cada arquivo.

Conheço apenas um artigo que fala de técnicas de determinação diferentes de cache, e [você pode consulta-lo aqui](http://www.academia.edu/955457/T%C3%A9cnicas_de_Web_Caching_e_Prefetching_com_Prioridades).
Espero que tenha sido útil.

Comment: Olá, @nessoila! Bem-vinda ao SOpt, percebo que você tem se esforçado em responder uma série de questões. Uma dica que poderia agregar valor às suas postagens, seria ao menos um resumo dos pontos essenciais dos links recomendados (mantendo a referência, claro), para que as pessoas não dependam demais das fontes externas (que como você já deve saber bem, podem deixar de existir a qualquer momento). Caso tenha interesse, vale à pena uma visita ao http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com, que é voltado à discussão sobre o funcionamento do site.

Comment: valeu a dica @Bacco :) vou ler as recomendações completas do link. pode deixar,

Comment: Obrigado @nessoila, vou ler esse material, achei bastante útil.