# Website não atualiza em tempo real, problema de cache

Tags: php, html, linux, servidor

Meu website não atualiza na mesma hora que modifico um arquivo, leva muito tempo para as modificações apareçam, já tentei por meios de METAS TAGS, arquivo .manifest, e Pragma no PHP. Sem sucesso.

Apenas quando adiciono "?v=2" por exemplo, ele atualiza, fiz isso dinamicamente, pois se eu atualizar o arquivo, o "?v=2" já fica desatualizado e tenho que usar "?v=3". Não acontece com todos os sites da hospedagem.

Servidor LINUX com PHP 5.4.x.

Comment: Desculpa, mas não entendi direito, o cache acontece no arquivo php? Ou no javascript? Em qual dos arquivos você está modificando. Se for php, qual framework você está usando? Pois quem armazena cache é o browser ou o server, no caso do server ou é um config do framework ou está nas configurações da hospedagem.

Comment: Outra chance, onde você está testando? Faculdade, trabalho? A empresa não possui um sistema de cache próprio?

Comment: Eu mudei de servidor (Locaweb) e o problema persistiu, no entanto, criei outro index.php com o mesmo código, e este parou de dar cache, não preciso mais usar ?v=X. Muito estranho. Ao que tudo indica era problema no arquivo. Vou continuar os testes.

Comment: Boa noite Fabio, a resposta resolveu o problema?

Comment: Conseguiu resolver seu problema?

Comment: Consegui, apenas mudando de servidor mesmo, é alguma configuração de cache que nem o suporte da empresa pode me sanar o problema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se as páginas que você se refere são arquivos PHP geralmente eles não ficam em cache (variando de browser para browser), para evitar o cache crie um arquivo chamado `global.php` e adicione o seguinte conteudo:

```
<?php
$g = gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s');
header('Expires: ' . $g . ' GMT');
header('Last-Modified: ' . $g . ' GMT');
header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0', false);
header('Pragma: no-cache');
```

E use `include` para adicionar este arquivo em todos seus arquivos PHP necessários, por exemplo no `index.php`

```
<?php
include 'global.php';

...Resto arquivo...
```

As páginas que já estão em cache continuarão até expirar, mas assim que expirar elas nunca mais ficarão em cache.

Porém vou ser sincero, se forem arquivos PHP é bem provável que você já esteja usando "headers" para fazer o cache, talvez você esteja usando algum framework e isto não tem como responder.

Outra possibilidade é que existe algum arquivo `.htaccess` que está causando isto.

Se o código acima que citei não funcionar por favor edite a sua pergunta e adicione detalhes. Espero que ajude.

Se o caso for de arquivos estáticos, como `.js`, `.css`, `.html`, `.jpg`, etc. você poderá usar o próprio `.htaccess` para prevenir o cache (se bem que não recomendo, pois arquivos estáticos raramente tem modificações e o melhor seria usar cache neles). Exemplo ([SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11724596/1518921)):

```
<filesMatch "\.(?i:html|htm)$">
  FileETag None
  <ifModule mod_headers.c>
     Header unset ETag
     Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
     Header set Pragma "no-cache"
     Header set Expires "Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT"
  </ifModule>
</filesMatch>
```

Neste exemplo apenas o arquivo `.html` e `.htm` não ficarão no cache.

<sub>**Relatado:** [É possível usar if-modified-since com “304 not modified” sem PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/44141/3635)</sub>

Comment: Amigo, gostei muito da sua resposta, vou tentar essa alternativa e posto aqui o resultado. Eu achei que tinha solucionado, mas na verdade o problema persiste. Muito obrigado.

Comment: @FabioWeydson você testou abrir o navegador em modo anonimo e verificar se está ocorrendo o cache?

Answer (score 0):

tente usar esse script tava com um problema semelhante e resolveu

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
setInterval(function(){cache_clear()},3000);
});
function cache_clear()
{
window.location.reload(true);
}
</script>
```