# Qual o motivo do sufixo "?algumnumero" no link de alguns CSS?

Tags: css

Estava vendo as fontes de alguns sites, e por vezes vejo algo assim:

```
<link href="http://css.siteX.com/imagecache/.../ymPrompt.css?2014102701" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Gostaria de entender o porquê do `?2014102701`.. Têm alguma utilidade?

Pode ser algo para diminuir a probabilidade de dar erro na requisição a este documento quando o site está cheio?

Comment: Isso força a não pegar cache de versões velhas do CSS. Eu particularmente prefiro versionar já no nome do arquivo se é pra fazer isso, em vez de salvar com nome igual.

Comment: hahaha.. Realmente, versionar é uma boa, já que se o site é constante e não há modificação na estrutura do arquivo todo o dia então deixar em cache é melhor para experiência do usuário né..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Isto é usado para prevenir cache em arquivos que foram atualizados, no caso para o navegador (ou software cliente que suporta HTTP) ele considera essas urls endereços diferentes e portanto para cada um será gerado um cache diferente:

```
//exemplo.com/static/css/style.css
//exemplo.com/static/css/style.css?
//exemplo.com/static/css/style.css?0000
//exemplo.com/static/css/style.css?0001
```

Então a cada modificação do arquivo `style.css` é alterado o valor do sufixo para prevenir que o navegador carregue o arquivo de cache.

Por exemplo, a url inicial é:

```
//exemplo.com/static/css/style.css?1428260681
```

Este numero na frente (`?1428260681`) é o [unix-time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) da última modificação do `style.css`, quando editar ele uma linguagem de server-side (ou algo equivalente) por exemplo faz a detecção do ultima modificação e adiciona um novo numero ao sufixo, um exemplo como PHP:

```
//Pega o arquivo pelo caminho real e retorna a última modificação em segundos
$utlima_modificao = filemtime('/home/user/www/project/static/style.css');
```

E usamos assim:

```
<link href="static/style.css?<?php echo $utlima_modificao; ?>">
```

A variavel `$utlima_modificao` irá retornar um numero em segundos (unix-time) da última modificação, portanto se houver modificação o numero será diferente.

Desta maneira se houver alguma modificação no arquivo CSS (ou JS) podemos prevenir que os usuários acabem acessando a versão antiga que pode estar em cache.

Note que está é uma técnica básica de exemplo, existem muitas outras, por este motivo nem sempre os sufixos usados serão o tempo em segundos da última modificação.

### Relatado:

Se quiser saber como fazer cache dos arquivos estáticos, leia o link: [É possivel usar if-modified-since com “304 not modified” sem PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/44178/3635)