# Como fazer o upload de uma imagem que pode ser atualizada mas permanece com o mesmo nome?

Tags: php, upload, file-upload

Olá. Como o próprio título da questão já diz, gostaria de saber como fazer o upload de um arquivo em png, jpg ou jpeg em que seu nome seja sempre mantido como profilepic. no diretório ['DOCUMENT_ROOT']/images.
Como fazer isso? Já tentei ler alguns tutoriais até aqui mesmo do StackOverflow, não cheguei a uma conclusão. Evidente que não estou procurando por um código pronto, só que todos os códigos apontam como se houvessem múltiplos usuários com nomes aleatórios etc. Agradeço desde já.

Meu código:

```
<?php
$target_dir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/gh-pages/images/profilepic.png';
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
$check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
if($check !== false) {
    echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
    $uploadOk = 1;
} else {
    echo "File is not an image.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
echo "File is too large!";
$uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType !="jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
$uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
    echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
} else {
    echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
}
}
?>
```

Erros:

> ( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: fileToUpload in C:\wamp64\www\gh-pages\installation\uploadprofilepic.php on line 3
>   Call Stack
>   Time    Memory  Function    Location
>   1   0.0011  241736  {main}( )   ...\uploadprofilepic.php:0
>
> ( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: fileToUpload in C:\wamp64\www\gh-pages\installation\uploadprofilepic.php on line 18
>   Call Stack
>   Time    Memory  Function    Location
>   1   0.0011  241736  {main}( )   ...\uploadprofilepic.php:0
>
> ( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: fileToUpload in C:\wamp64\www\gh-pages\installation\uploadprofilepic.php on line 33
>   Call Stack
>       Time    Memory  Function    Location
>   1   0.0011  241736  {main}( )   ...\uploadprofilepic.php:0

Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.

Comment: Por que não gerar um nome aleatório e ligá-lo ao usuário salvando o nome gerado no banco de dados?

Comment: Meu projeto não funciona bem assim. Não tenho múltiplos usuários. Preciso de apenas um arquivo com nome invariável. também procuro uma alternativa completamente sem SQL @LeoLetto

Comment: Acho qeu está faltando um enctype="multipart/form-data" no seu formulário de upload (é isso ou o upload de arquivos está desabilitado em seu php.ini)

Answer (score 4):

Para fazer o upload é necessário que o `<form>` tenha o atributo `enctype="multipart/form-data"` e `method="POST"`, como expliquei em:

- [Upload não funciona $_FILES undefined index error](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/50988/3635)

Assim por exemplo:

```
<form action="upload.php" method="POST">
    <input type="file" name="foto_profile">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
```

O upload pode ser assim (usei esta checagem do tipo do arquivo https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/73497/3635):

```
<?php

$name = 'profilepic'; //Sem extensão

/*
Troque aqui conforme a necessidade
Se o arquivo de upload estiver na mesma pasta que a pasta
./gh-pages pode fazer isso:

$caminhosite = 'gh-pages/images/';
*/
$caminhosite = 'http://localhost/gh-pages/images/';

$location = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/gh-pages/images/';
$folderexists = is_dir($location);

function mimeType($file)
{
    $mimetype = false;

    if (class_exists('finfo')) {//PHP5.4+
        $finfo     = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
        $mimetype  = finfo_file($finfo, $file);
        finfo_close($finfo);
    } else if (function_exists('mime_content_type')) {//php5.3 ou inferiror
        $mimetype = mime_content_type($file);
    }

    return $mimetype;
}

//Tenta criar a pasta se ela não existir
if (!$folderexists) {
    //Usei o 0644 para acaso o servidor seja linux
    $folderexists = mkdir($diretorio, 0644, true);
}

if (!$folderexists) {
    echo 'A pasta não existe e não foi possível cria-la';
} else if (isset($_FILES['foto_profile'])) {
    $tmp_name = $_FILES['foto_profile']['tmp_name'];

    $error = $_FILES['foto_profile']['error'];

    if ($error !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        echo 'Erro ao fazer o upload:', $error;
    } else {

        $permitidos = array(
            'jpeg', 'png', 'gif'
        );

        $info = mimeType($rowData['imagem']);

        //Transforma image/jpeg em jpeg por exemplo
        $info = str_replace('image/', '', $infos);
        $info = str_replace('x-', '', $infos);

        /*
         * Adiciona extensão ao nome da foto, podendo ficar como:
         * profilepic.jpeg ou profilepic.png ou profilepic.gif
         */
        $name .= '.' . $info;

        if (!in_array($infos, $permitidos)) {
            echo 'O tipo de arquivo enviado é inválido, permitido somente imagens';
        } else if (move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $location . $name)) {
            echo 'Upload completado, veja a foto<br>';

            $urlfoto = $caminhosite . $name . '?' . filemtime($location . $name);

            echo '<img src="' . $urlfoto . '">';
        } else {
            echo 'Erro ao mover o arquivo';
        }
    }
} else {
    echo 'Selecione um arquivo para fazer upload';
}
```

### Evitando o cache

No momento de exibir a imagem pode existir uma versão em cache no navegador do usuário, para evitar você pode usar *querystring* como expliquei nesta resposta

- [Qual o motivo do sufixo "?algumnumero" no link de alguns CSS?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/57048/3635)

Neste formato:

```
http://site.com/images/profilepic.jpg?{unixtime da última atualização da foto}
```

Por exemplo:

```
http://site.com/images/profilepic.jpg?102992929292
```

Para resolver isto [filemtime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php) assim:

```
<?php
//Supondo que o caminho seja relativo
$caminho = '/gh-pages/images/profilepic.jpg';
$urlfoto = '/gh-pages/images/profilepic.jpg?' . filemtime($caminho);
?>

<img src="<?php echo $urlfoto; ?>">
```

A cada vez que atualiza o arquivo o arquivo incorpora uma data de modificação, isto faz com que seja possível saber qual a última da que o arquivo foi atualizado.

Pro navegador isto (esse numero na frente é *unixtime* que representa dia 18 de Abril de 2016):

```
http://site.com/gh-pages/images/profilepic.jpg?1460971238595
```

É diferente disto (representa 5 de dezembro 2016):

```
http://site.com/gh-pages/images/profilepic.jpg?1480971302550
```

Mas ainda será a mesma foto, no entanto a cada vez que fizer o upload a prõrpia função vai detectar a nova data e vai trocar o unixtime na querystring.

Comment: Explique esse $caminhodosite? Quer dizer que tenho que editar para corresponder ao domínio ou posso usar caminhos relativos/absolutos? @GuilhermeNascimento

Comment: @MucaP esse caminho absoluto pode ser facilmente trocado por relativo, só vai depender de onde esta a chamada da página de upload, então você pode trocar esta linha linha `$urlfoto = $caminhosite . $name . '?' . filemtime($location . $name);` por apenas `$urlfoto = $name . '?' . filemtime($location . $name);`, na verdade essa $caminhoabsoluto não tem nada haver com o upload, só coloquei pra facilitar o entendimento do que é caminho "lógico" e "caminho http" ;)

Comment: Infelizmente, tenho erros nas linhas 53, 56, 57, 65 e 23.

Answer (score 0):

acho que existe três soluções para isso:

1. Caso exista só um usuário: Quando o usuário for fazer a troca da imagem você teria que deletar a foto atual e renovar a nova com o nome profilepic
2. caso exista vários usuários, você pode usar a lógica de cima porém aplicando em uma pasta dentro de imagens ficando assim /imagem/id_do_usuario/profilepic
3. e em ultimo caso, não sei se aplica direito ao que falou, poderia ter um arquivo chamado profilepic.php que receberia como parâmetro o id do usuário.

Comment: 2 e 3 são inúteis, desculpe a expressão. A 1, ok, eu sei apagar a imagem, mas como fazer que o nome seja sempre o mesmo?