# Como desabilitar cache da pagina

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, imagem, cache

Tenho uma página que salva a foto do usuário, ao editar a foto o cache sempre continua pegando a foto antiga pra exibir. Já tentei usar : 





e tentei usar algumas variações disso e nao funciona. Alguem sabe alguma outra forma?

Comment: Pode usar o nome da foto com o sufixo baseado no timestamp da ultima atualização, por exemplo `<img src="foto.jpg?<?=filemtime('foto.jpg');?>">`, então a cada vez que atualizar a foto o filemtime vai ser diferente, o que muda a URL e contorna o cache, como expliquei na resposta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/169846/3635

Answer (score 0):

Há uma forma muito simples de contornar a cache dos browsers, se alterar o nome da imagem o browser irá "pensar" que é uma nova imagem e não assume a cache da antiga.

Outra opção é no ficheiro `.htaccess` adicionar esta regra

```
<FilesMatch "\.(gif|ico|jpe|jpeg|jpg|js|png)$">
    <IfModule mod_expires.c>
        ExpiresActive Off
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        FileETag None
        Header unset ETag
        Header unset Pragma
        Header unset Cache-Control
        Header unset Last-Modified
        Header set Pragma "no-cache"
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
        Header set Expires "Mon, 10 Apr 1972 00:00:00 GMT"
    </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```