# Duvida Sobre Cache

Tags: cache, pagespeed-insights

estou fazendo meu site, e quero tentar atingir 100/100 no PageSpeed Insights, eu ativei meu cache pelo .htacces, mas o P.S.I diz que ainda está inativo, então fui ver os headers, e volta isso:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 21 Apr 2016 14:54:41 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.34
Content-Encoding: gzip
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Expires: Thu, 21 Apr 2016 14:54:41 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=2, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```

pelo que notei o Cache-Control ta max-age=0, não sei sei isso que dizer que está off ou se está pegando, nunca usei cache em meus sites, e não sei nada sobre, meu .htaccess está assim:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .(/)?$ index.php

SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI "\.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$" no-gzip

ExpiresActive On

ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/cache-manifest "access plus 0 seconds"

# Html
ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 0 seconds"

# Data
ExpiresByType text/xml "access plus 0 seconds"
ExpiresByType application/xml "access plus 0 seconds"
ExpiresByType application/json "access plus 0 seconds"

# Feed
ExpiresByType application/rss+xml "access plus 1 hour"
ExpiresByType application/atom+xml "access plus 1 hour"

# Favicon
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 week"

# Media: images, video, audio
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType video/ogg "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType audio/ogg "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType video/mp4 "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType video/webm "access plus 1 month"

# HTC files
ExpiresByType text/x-component "access plus 1 month"

# Webfonts
ExpiresByType application/x-font-ttf "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType font/opentype "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-font-woff "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/svg+xml "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject "access plus 1 month"

# CSS / JS
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript  "access plus 1 year"
```

Quero muito que o Cache fique ativo, mas não consigo deixar ele, já procurei sobre, já mudei meu .htaccess, já cheguei a ver vídeo do Google sobre isso, mas não consigo entender por que ainda está dando como offline!

Seria possível alguém me ajudar nessa questão e se puder, me explicar sobre esse tipo de código?

Link do PageSpeed Insight: https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fprocurar.netescola.info%2Fp%2Fhardwell

Comment: Veja se esta resposta ajuda http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/120344/3635

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, li isso e re-li ele várias vezes, e fiz oq ele diz, mas o P.S.I Continua dizendo que é para apoveitar o Cache do Navegador, Olha aqui https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fprocurar.netescola.info%2Fp%2Fhardwell

Comment: Raphael eu respondi, veja se deu pra entender.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seu código está funcionando perfeitamente, o problema é que você não pode definir cache de arquivos externos, no caso os links que não tem um bom aproveitamento de cache são esses:

```
https://i.ytimg.com/vi/iSxbI3d0064/hqdefault.jpg (5 minutes)
https://i.ytimg.com/vi/-IZc6i5K2OQ/hqdefault.jpg (2 hours)
https://i.ytimg.com/vi/3t9O5DpRfxU/hqdefault.jpg (2 hours)
https://i.ytimg.com/vi/4KDQ0IjMsnA/hqdefault.jpg (2 hours)
https://i.ytimg.com/vi/4QTwsLTv4Kc/hqdefault.jpg (2 hours)
https://i.ytimg.com/vi/4Uw8EcNmLC4/hqdefault.jpg (2 hours)
https://i.ytimg.com/vi/4cLtiYvRvfE/hqdefault.jpg (2 hours)
https://i.ytimg.com/vi/ALM1CwRMrmw/hqdefault.jpg (2 hours)
https://i.ytimg.com/vi/AQ0resnXCcE/hqdefault.jpg (2 hours)
https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Br-mOQ_x-Ik/hqdefault.jpg (2 hours)
https://i.ytimg.com/vi/EU1SaAun2r0/hqdefault.jpg (2 hours)
https://i.ytimg.com/vi/EoYOCxP6yIA/hqdefault.jpg (2 hours)
https://i.ytimg.com/vi/F2vea_JoBaw/hqdefault.jpg (2 hours)
https://i.ytimg.com/vi/TCZpKB7l8-Y/hqdefault.jpg (2 hours)
https://i.ytimg.com/vi/U1aXAYjgy5w/hqdefault.jpg (2 hours)
https://i.ytimg.com/vi/ULwcsIPdc8w/hqdefault.jpg (2 hours)
https://i.ytimg.com/vi/W_sFQN8RL1E/hqdefault.jpg (2 hours)
https://i.ytimg.com/vi/WuCGE6Sl27w/hqdefault.jpg (2 hours)
https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Y-D7PHnn70k/hqdefault.jpg (2 hours)
https://i.ytimg.com/vi/byZO3dMLtpA/hqdefault.jpg (2 hours)
https://i.ytimg.com/vi/clRjbYa4UWQ/hqdefault.jpg (2 hours)
https://i.ytimg.com/vi/eBZjZ6eAzMw/hqdefault.jpg (2 hours)
https://i.ytimg.com/vi/iQpGq4HguVs/hqdefault.jpg (2 hours)
https://i.ytimg.com/vi/lSLwVPih4_w/hqdefault.jpg (2 hours)
https://i.ytimg.com/vi/m1ssAFzaCsU/hqdefault.jpg (2 hours)
https://i.ytimg.com/vi/qLKGcB4uE-g/hqdefault.jpg (2 hours)
https://i.ytimg.com/vi/rTisfEc786c/hqdefault.jpg (2 hours)
https://i.ytimg.com/vi/rhUvo4xj2oU/hqdefault.jpg (2 hours)
https://i.ytimg.com/vi/wdvI62lq78I/hqdefault.jpg (2 hours)
https://i.ytimg.com/vi/wkGH7W8WPYU/hqdefault.jpg (2 hours)
https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js (2 hours)
```

Veja nenhum pertence ao seu domínio, o Google incentiva varias boas praticas, mas as próprias ferramentas deles (google analytics e youtube) raramente seguem isso.

Conseguir 100/100 no [PageSpeed Insights](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/) não significa que o seu site esta ótimo para o usuário final, a sua página por exemplo usa a tag `<style>` em um momento, quando poderia estar dentro e um `.CSS` que aproveitaria o cache e tem uma tag `<script>` com uma função chamada `function tocar(id)`, poderia estar dentro de um `.JS` .

Existem vários links na sua página de **share** que poderiam ser automatizados através de jQuery (que você já faz o uso) ou Javascript puro mesmo, ao invés de fazer assim:

```
<p class="center no"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?app_id=1731086990510840&u=http://procurar.netescola.info/baixar/iSxbI3d0064&display=popup&ref=plugin&src=share_button" class="fb" target="_blank" title="Compartilhar Música no Facebook"><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i><br>Compartilhar</a></p>
```

Poderia ser algo como:

```
<p class="center no"><a href="javascript:void(0);" data-video-id="iSxbI3d0064" class="fb" title="Compartilhar Música no Facebook"><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i><br>Compartilhar</a></p>
```

E no jQuery algo como:

```
$(document).on("click", ".fb", function() {
    var url = 'https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?app_id=1731086990510840&u=http://procurar.netescola.info/baixar/' +
               $(this).data("video-id") +
              '&display=popup&ref=plugin&src=share_button';

    window.open(url, "_blank");
}, false);
```

Mas são apenas sugestões e tem várias maneiras de resolver isto.

Agora pra resolver o problema de requisições externas você poderia tentar resolver isto é usando um "proxy" em uma linguagem de programação, não recomendo aplicar a tudo, apenas nas imagens de thumbnail do youtube.

Crie um arquivo chamado thumb.php:

```
<?php
$time = 365 * 24 * 60 * 60; //Defina o tempo de cache aqui, por padrão deixei o cache de 365 dias
$cacheThumbPath = 'thumbcache/'; //Defina a sua pasta de cache aqui (mantenha a / no final)

$http_version = empty($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL']) ? 'HTTP/1.0' : $_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'];

if (empty($_GET['id']) || !preg_match('/^[A-Za-z0-9_\-]{11}$/', $_GET['id'])) {
    header($http_version . '400 Bad Request', true, 400);
    echo 'ID não definida na url';
    exit;
}

$id = $_GET['id'];
$cacheThumbPath .= $id . '.jpg';

function cachePage()
{
    global $http_version, $time;

    header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
    header('Expires: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', time() + $time) . ' GMT');
    header('Cache-Control: public, max-age=' . $time);
    header('Pragma: max-age=' . $time);
}

//Verifica se já existe uma cópia do arquivo no seu servidor para evitar requisitar várias vezes o youtube
if (file_exists($cacheThumbPath)) {
    cachePage();
    echo file_get_contents($cacheThumbPath);
    exit;
}

$ch = curl_init();

$thumburl = 'https://i.ytimg.com/vi/' . $id . '/hqdefault.jpg';

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $thumburl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);

$data = curl_exec($ch) or die(curl_error($ch));

curl_close($ch);

//Salva cópia do arquivo no seu servidor
if (file_put_contents($cacheThumbPath, $data)) {
    cachePage();
    echo $data;
    exit;
}

header($http_version . ' 500 Internal Server Error', true, 500);
echo 'Erro ao baixar ou ler a imagem, detalhes:';
print_r(error_get_last());
```

E no HTML chame ele assim:

```
<div class="capayt" style="height:350px; background:url('http://netescola.info/thumb.php?id=m1ssAFzaCsU');" alt="Hardwell Live at Ultra Music Festival Miami 2016 - Procurar Musicas"></div>
```

Comment: Pocha, queria tanto o 100/100, mas realmente o google tirou isso de mim, obrigado por sua resposta, se souber se tem alguma forma de eu fazer esses links ai passarem para meu cache de alguma forma, pensei em 64bits data, mas sei lá, se soube alguma forma boa e puder me informar por mensagem, eu agradeço, vlw pela resposta.

Comment: Acho que apenas com um "webproxy" (escrito dentro do teu servidor), você usa php em suas páginas?

Comment: Uso sim, meu site é completamente em PHP, eu uso api's do google e do soundcloud

Comment: Amigão, eu fui tomar um banho para abrir a mente, e consegui pensar em algo, ficou assim `header('Content-Type: image/png');
echo file_get_contents(urldecode($_GET['i']));` em funcionamento: http://netescola.info/teste.php?i=https://i.ytimg.com/vi/FZLIcQf47TQ/hqdefault.jpg

Comment: @RaphaelCaldas adicionei um exemplo que vai evitar fazer várias requisições nos servidores externos.

Comment: Caramba cara, eu não pensei em fazer dessa forma, MUITO OBRIGADO MESMO, eu tava dando vários requests em externo e fiquei com medo de alguma hora lagar, isso me ajudou demais, demais mesmo, muito obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: @RaphaelCaldas não se esqueça de fazer as melhorias de JS e CSS que citei, e um detalhe eu coloquei o cache de 6 dias, mas sendo fotos dos videos acho que você pode colocar um tempo maior de cache, como 1 ano por exemplo: `$time = 365 * 24 * 60 * 60;`

Comment: Essa alteração do jQuery eu vou ver, quero ver se fica bom em mobile, por que uma boa parte do publico pode ser mobile, por que no pc tem Spotify que é melhor, mas no Mobile o Spotify só presta o premium, e sobre o css, eu vou ver mais, vou dar uma estudada, pq o google diz q é bom, mas se fosse tão bom, eles mesmos colocariam nos deles, MUITO OBRIGADO pela ajuda que me deu, realmente me ajudou mt.

Comment: A dos links em share que citei  com jQuery é opcional e era apenas uma sugestão, mas a tag <script> que contem a função e tocar e a tag style acho que seria bom já mover pra arquivos .js e .css respectivamente =) @RaphaelCaldas - Estava com um erro na função jquery, agora corrigi `$(document).on("click", ".fb", function()`