# Código para Aproveitar cache do navegador deixa o site fora do ar

Tags: wordpress, htaccess

Bom, estou tendo um problema para tirar o bendito "Aproveitar cache do navegador" do PageSpeed Insights.O site que estou fazendo isso é em Wordpress. A internet inteira indica um mesmo código para ser inserido no arquivo .htaccess, seja em inglês ou português, que é o seguinte:

```
# COMEÇA BROWSER CACHE

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg “access plus 1 year”
ExpiresByType image/jpeg “access plus 1 year”
ExpiresByType image/gif “access plus 1 year”
ExpiresByType image/png “access plus 1 year”
ExpiresByType text/css “access plus 1 month”
ExpiresByType application/pdf “access plus 1 month”
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript “access plus 1 month”
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash “access plus 1 month”
ExpiresByType image/x-icon “access plus 1 year”
ExpiresByType application/javascript “access plus 1 month”
ExpiresDefault “access plus 2 days”
</IfModule>

# TERMINA BROWSER CACHE
```

Só que sempre que eu uso esse, o site fica fora do ar, não sei porque isso ocorre, já usei esse mesmo código em outros sites e não ficou assim.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém saberia me dizer se houve alguma mudança e essa forma não está funcionando mais?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema são as aspas `“` e `”`, este tipo de aspas não funciona, deve substituir por `"` para ambos:

```bsh
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresDefault "access plus 2 days"
</IfModule>
```

### Sobre o PageSpeed Insights

- [Duvida Sobre Cache](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/124656/3635)
- [Guardar ou não cache do navegador?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/120344/3635)

### Sobre Etag

- [É possível usar if-modified-since com “304 not modified” sem PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/44141/3635)

Comment: Era isso mesmo, amigo. Muito obrigado.

Answer (score 2):

eu uso esse código em alguns sites e ele funciona, faça um teste no seu projeto, altere apenas o prazo de cada item que pode ser diferente para você !

```
#Força a utilizar Cache-Control e Expires header
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header unset ETag
</IfModule>
FileETag None
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive on
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType text/cache-manifest "access plus 0 seconds"
    # HTML
    ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 0 seconds"
    # DATA
    ExpiresByType text/xml "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/xml "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/json "access plus 0 seconds"
    # FEED
    ExpiresByType application/rss+xml "access plus 1 hour"
    ExpiresByType application/atom+xml "access plus 1 hour"
    # FAVICON
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 week"
    # MEDIA: IMAGES, VIDEO, AUDIO
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType video/ogg "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType audio/ogg "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType video/mp4 "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType video/webm "access plus 1 month"
    # HTC files
    ExpiresByType text/x-component "access plus 1 month"
    # WEBFONTS
    ExpiresByType application/x-font-ttf "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType font/opentype "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/x-font-woff "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/svg+xml "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject "access plus 1 month"
    # CSS / JS
    ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType application/x-javascript  "access plus 1 year"
</IfModule>
```