# Como otimizar o site conforme resposta da análise?

Tags: wordpress, htaccess, otimização, pagespeed-insights

Recentemente fiz um blog para minha esposa, https://danielafolle.com.br/ o qual agora estou trabalhando para otimizar o tempo de resposta do site.

Estou usando o [PageSpeed Insights](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/) do Google para me basear se estou progredindo na otimização.

No final da analise, ele gera um relatório dizendo quais pontos podem serem melhorados para otimizar o site.

Ao analisar o [Site](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=danielafolle.com.br) me voltam 4 respostas que não consigo otimizar.

```
Eliminar JavaScript e CSS de bloqueio de renderização no conteúdo
acima da borda; 
Aproveitar cache do navegador;
Ativar compactação;
Otimizar imagens.
```

O primeiro e o ultimo problema tudo bem, pois o primeiro tem haver com o plugin [Autoptimize](https://br.wordpress.org/plugins/autoptimize/) do Wordpress que insere o CSS na página e o último são as imagens que estão relacionados ao Adsense.

Acontece que a compactação e o reaproveitamento de cache do navegador estão ativos no .htacess do Wordpress.

**Deflate - GZip**

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/atom_xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-httpd-php
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-httpd-fastphp
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-httpd-eruby
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html

SetOutputFilter DEFLATE

BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html

BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4.0[678] no-gzip

BrowserMatch ^HMSI[E] !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html

SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI .(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip dont-vary
</IfModule>
```

**E o aproveitamento de cache:**

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header unset ETag
</IfModule>
 FileETag None
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive on
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/cache-manifest "access plus 0 seconds"
# Html
ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 0 seconds"
# Data
ExpiresByType text/xml "access plus 0 seconds"
ExpiresByType application/xml "access plus 0 seconds"
ExpiresByType application/json "access plus 0 seconds"
# Feed
ExpiresByType application/rss+xml "access plus 1 hour"
ExpiresByType application/atom+xml "access plus 1 hour"
# Favicon
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 week"
# Media: images, video, audio
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType video/ogg "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType audio/ogg "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType video/mp4 "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType video/webm "access plus 1 month"
# HTC files
ExpiresByType text/x-component "access plus 1 month"
# Webfonts
ExpiresByType application/x-font-ttf "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType font/opentype "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-font-woff "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/svg+xml "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject "access plus 1 month"
# CSS / JS
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 1 year"
</IfModule>
#Força o IE a sempre carregar utilizando a última versão disponível
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header set X-UA-Compatible "IE=Edge,chrome=1"
<FilesMatch "\.(js|css|gif|png|jpeg|pdf|xml|oga|ogg|m4a|ogv|mp4|m4v|webm|svg|svgz|eot|ttf|otf|woff|ico|webp|appcache|manifest|htc|crx|oex|xpi|safariextz|vcf)$" >
Header unset X-UA-Compatible
</FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

Pode ser que errei algum parametro na configuração do meu .htacess?

Comment: Relacionada: [Dúvida sobre cache](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/124645/duvida-sobre-cache)

Comment: Em relação a otimização de link's externos ok. Mas e a compactação que não está funcionando? Pode ser o html do adsense?

Comment: Não consigo ajudar em tudo, mas você pode realizar a compactação das imagens também em algum site, pois ajuda na performance.