# Combinação de linguagens que se tem um melhor desempenho para Web

Tags: aplicação-web

Muitos utilizam PHP + HTML para criar páginas Web, porém não acontece o mesmo com grandes sites como as "redes sociais" (Facebook, Youtube, Instagram, LinkedIn, etc...).

Então gostaria de saber quais são as linguagens combinadas que se obtém um melhor desempenho para desenvolvimento web tanto para projetos GRANDES como PEQUENOS, já que "*aparentemente*" não são PHP + HTML *com base nelas*. A combinação de ASP.Net + C# poderia também ser uma boa combinação?

> Não sei quais tags adicionar, alguém poderia me ajudar editando a pergunta pfv?

Comment: Em 99.9% dos casos, rapidez no desenvolvimento e facilidade na manutenção são preferíveis em vez de desempenho. A mão de obra geralmente é mais cara do que recursos computacionais. Por isso utilizam PHP e HTML(obrigatório pra sistemas web), ou qualquer outra linguagem de script. Mas se você quer desempenho, pode fazer seu código em C, que escuta a rede e responde de acordo com o protocolo HTTP, ou até mesmo algo parecido em assembly.

Comment: Facebook usa/usava PHP. Eles usavam o HPHPc, agora supostamente usam o HHVM que é o sucessor do HPHPc. Ele suporta o "Hack" e o "PHP". Tal HHVM (http://hhvm.com/) foi desenvolvido pelo próprio Facebook, salvo engano. Antes do PHP 7 o HHVM era extremamente superior em velocidade. Hoje o HHVM vs PHP 7 possuem diferenças menores, porém o HHVM é em geral mais rápido do que o PHP 7. Salvo engano o HHVM compila o código em C++, isso ajuda a imensamente na performance. Pode ler mais em  https://goo.gl/0nnbYi.

Comment: Tudo depende muito de qual é a definição de desempenho que te interessa. E se você perguntar "*o que é desempenho?*" para dez programadores experientes diferentes, obterá dez respostas completamente diferentes. Além disso, como a resposta do Guilherme Nascimento demonstra abaixo, a escolha da linguagem de programação provavelmente é o fator de menor importância nisso.

Comment: Por fim, é preciso levar em conta qual é o cenário que realmente te interessa como fator de desempenho. Por exemplo, de nada serve usar uma linguagem de programação super-otimizada para triturar bilhões de números em matrizes e fazer os cálculos mais malucos que você imagina e que bate todas as outras em benchmarks sobre isso, se o seu objetivo é implementar um site de uma rede social.

Answer (score 8):

Combinação nada tem a ver. Na verdade, as linguagens de programação nada tem a ver com a performance de maneira significativa, pois o que influencia é como você as usa, ou seja, como você programa, independente de quão bem ela foi projetada.

### Fatores que influenciam na perda de performance:

- Código back-end mal-escrito.
- Não aproveitar cache.
- Conexões no banco de dados sem necessidade.
- Frameworks que consomem muito do servidor para aplicações pequenas.
- Código front-end com um grande número *resources* ou bibliotecas e CSS que geralmente são usados sem necessidade.
- Um servidor (**máquina** + **rede**) fraco:

  **Este talvez seja o item mais importante**, geralmente um servidor *shared* é compartilhado com inúmeros clientes que hospedam seus sites. Na verdade, a maioria das pessoas usam *shared* ou VPS (que também é compartilhado, mas tem um número menor de clientes) para hospedar seus sites. Esses servidores geralmente não aguentam muito tráfego.
- Quanto mais usuários acessando, melhor a máquina precisará ser.

Esses são alguns pontos. Ou seja, não adianta contratar o melhor tipo de servidor sendo que não vai usar tudo, a questão é **planejar** e **projetar**, se o site terá um grande tráfego então terá que contratar um servidor melhor, desde um VPS até um dedicado.

Em todos casos o bom é sempre fazer proveito do cache, isso varia de linguagem para linguagem (back-end). Um exemplo que posso lhe citar é você fazer cache dos arquivos estáticos, como imagens, ícones, js, css:

- [É possível usar if-modified-since com “304 not modified” sem PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/44141/3635)
- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/120344/3635

**Não existe caminho pronto** ou **fórmula mágica** para conseguir o resultado desejado, o que existe são alguns passos como:

- No front-end adicionar apenas js, css e imagens que realmente vai usar.
- No back-end incluir classes que realmente vai usar.
- Conectar ao um banco de dados ou webservice somente se necessitar.
- Fazer um bom aproveitamento do cache.
- E o mais importante é escolher um tipo servidor conforme o tráfego que pretende atingir.

### Sobre os benchmark:

O benchmark é uma operação realizada a fim de avaliar os desempenho de um software ou compará-lo com outro. Você vai encontrar muitos comparativos sobre as linguagens back-end, mas isso é apenas um fator e geralmente no resultado final ele nem sempre vai ser válido, quero dizer que realmente existem algumas linguagens que tem uma performance um pouco melhor, mas isso não significa que você usar ela vai tornar as suas páginas rápidas de verdade.

Eu não vou postar nenhum resultado de benchmark porque a maioria se baseiam em frameworks prontos ou porque geralmente as diferentes linguagens operam em diferentes tipos de servidores (**sistema operacional** e **servidor http**), o que importa entender é que o que tem maior influência são:

- Sua escolha de servidor para contratar.
- Como você configura este servidor (se tiver opção de configurar).
- Como você programa e desenvolve.

Comment: Pode me indicar algum link, que contenha a melhor forma e em que operações são usados o cache ? Para um site pequeno de produtos.

Comment: @MagicHat adicionado ;)

Comment: Tks...Vlw ....................................

Comment: Eu acho que o servidores e rede é um dos fatores principais. Eu possui apenas um servidor dedicado por muito tempo (era 2x Deca-Core com 128GB de RAM). Porém nele o PHP e o MySQL eram juntos, há alguns muitos meses atrás. Até que decidir dividi-los entre um para o PHP e outro para o MySQL. Não deu outra, agora com cada um com 64GB (sim, é exagero!) e um deles com 1x Hexa-Core (o PHP) e o outro 2x Hexa-Core (MySQL) funcionam tranquilamente e estável. Uma outra coisa é remover o CPanel/Plesk e qualquer coisa que não seja o que precisa (Nginx, php, fast-cgi....).

Comment: @Inkeliz um ótimo exemplo complementar, a escolha do servidor já tinha adicionado, agora adicionei a lista "Como você configura este servidor (se tiver opção de configurar)", obrigado ;)