# Como instruir o navegador a manter meu Javascript e CSS em cache através do web.config

Tags: asp.net, http, cache

Eu analisei meu site novo no *Google PageSpeed Insights*, fiz algumas correções, e agora preciso cachear alguns arquivos(CSS e JS) no navegador.

Procurei alguns artigos/perguntas no Stack Overflow mas não consegui entender como cachear arquivos especificos. O resultado da análise é esse [aqui](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=guaranastock.com). Em especial, ele diz:

> **Aproveitar cache do navegador**
>
> A definição de uma data de validade ou de uma idade máxima nos cabeçalhos de HTTP para recursos estáticos instrui o navegador a carregar os recursos transferidos anteriormente a partir do disco local e não por meio da rede.

Eu entendi que isso se configura no *web.config*, mas não entendi como apontar apenas arquivos específicos. Gostaria pelo *web.config* e não dentro da página HTML.

Comment: Você poderia incluir o que o Google disse sobre o seu site na pergunta ("A definição de uma data de validade ou de uma idade máxima nos cabeçalhos de HTTP para recursos estáticos instrui o navegador a carregar os recursos transferidos anteriormente a partir do disco local e não por meio da rede") Eu faria isso, mas considero sempre melhor que o próprio autor coloque informação desse tipo.

Comment: Renan, basicamente esse é o objetivo da pergunta, eu não consigo achar onde configuro isso.

Comment: Existem várias formas de se conseguir o que você quer. [Encontrei](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2105481/how-to-cache-css-images-and-js) [algumas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/955792/browser-caching-in-asp-net-application) [no](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30075161/how-to-enable-browser-cache-for-images-css-and-js-files-separately-in-web-confi) [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2195266/how-to-configure-static-content-cache-per-folder-and-extension-in-iis7).

Comment: Minha sugestão: os navegadores atualmente já fazem esse controle caso você não dê indicação nenhuma no seu código, então eu não me preocuparia com isso agora - a não ser que você tenha problemas de tráfego ou carga que precise resolver agora.

Comment: Independente da minha sugestão acima, +1 porque eu gostaria de ter uma resposta canônica aqui. Vale recompensa pra quem for responder (me lembrem).

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Guardar ou não cache do navegador?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/94372/guardar-ou-n%c3%a3o-cache-do-navegador)

Comment: Eu quero fazer isso através do ASP.NET e não direto no HTML como na pergunta que você citou.

Comment: Qual é o seu servidor web e qual a vesão dele?

Comment: @LeonanCarvalho IIS Express, estou usando o .net framework 4.5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Arquivos estáticos como CSS, JS e até mesmo imagens podem ser armazenados no disco do cliente em forma de cache. Porém é importante que o servidor web diga que ele deve fazer cache ou não, e por quanto tempo. Muitos servidores web possuem a configuração específica para cada tipo de arquivo.

No caso do IIS express você deve usar o web.conf para fazer tais configurações de modo que o servidor entregue os headers corretamente para o cliente(navegador) fazer o cache de acordo. Esse cache é controlado pelo header Cache-Control.

[image: Exemplo do Cache-Control]

*Se quiser saber mais acesse https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/http-caching ( link em inglês).*

Para configurar o cache através do arquivo Web.config local, que é encontrado no diretório de conteúdo você deve configuar a tag `<caching>`.

Abaixo está uma amostra da configuração necessária para os arquivos js e css por 7 dias, que significa instruir o navegador à armazenar em cache todos os arquivos de js e de css por 7 dias.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
 <system.webServer>
    <caching enabled="true" enableKernelCache="true">
      <profiles>
        <add extension=".css" policy="CacheForTimePeriod" kernelCachePolicy="CacheForTimePeriod" duration="07:00:00"/>
        <add extension=".js" policy="CacheForTimePeriod" kernelCachePolicy="CacheForTimePeriod" duration="07:00:00"/>
      </profiles>
    </caching>
 </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Ainda é possível definir um cache para todos os arquivos estáticos sem distinção:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<configuration> 
  <system.webServer> 
        <staticContent> 
            <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="7.00:00:00" /> 
        </staticContent> 
  </system.webServer> 
</configuration>
```

A melhor política para manter os arquivos em cache é a que só modifica o arquivo quando ele é alterado. Isso aumenta o desempenho pois não faz com que o arquivo seja baixado novamente, o servidor irá controlar isso de forma interna. Para isso vamos usar a `policy`  `CacheUntilChange`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
 <system.webServer>
    <caching enabled="true" enableKernelCache="true">
      <profiles>
        <add extension=".css" policy="CacheUntilChange" kernelCachePolicy="CacheUntilChange"/>
        <add extension=".js" policy="CacheUntilChange" kernelCachePolicy="CacheUntilChange"/>
      </profiles>
    </caching>
 </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Para saber as variações de cada chave, combinações dos atributos e o que é permitido e outros exemplos acesse a documentação: https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/caching