# Otimização de site - Aproveitar cache do navegador

Tags: php, html, otimização

Estou otimizando meu site no PageSpeed Tools do Google.

Um item estou sem ideia do que fazer.

Lá consta:
Aproveitar cache do navegador
A definição de uma data de validade ou de uma idade máxima nos cabeçalhos de HTTP para recursos estáticos instrui o navegador a carregar os recursos transferidos anteriormente a partir do disco local e não por meio da rede.
Aproveite o cache do navegador para os seguintes recursos que podem ser armazenados em cache:

https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?hl=pt-BR (5 minutos)

https://www.google.com/…2/webworker.js?hl=pt-BR&v=v1523554879111 (5 minutos)

https://connect.facebook.net/pt_BR/sdk.js (20 minutos)

https://maps.googleapis.com/…=AIzaSyDh8ey5aysev9_03haI8BmrNhHAic9xX80 (30 minutos)

https://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js (60 minutos)

https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js (2 horas)

No htaccess o ExpiresByType está configurado por tipo de arquivo (gif, png, etc).

Seria possível criar uma condição no htaccess para aproveitar o cache do navegador nesses itens?

Comment: http://lorindo.com/aproveitando-o-cache-do-navegador/

Comment: https://www.codigofonte.com.br/dicas/usando-o-poder-do-cache-do-navegador-com-htaccess

Comment: Se resolveu, me informe, estou curioso.

Comment: Acredito que isso deve te ajudar https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/94372/guardar-ou-n%C3%A3o-cache-do-navegador

Answer (score -3):

Infelizmente não dá para colocar aproveitar cache de arquivos externos do seu servidor, o htaccess faz trabalho local, quem deveria solucionar estes problemas são as próprias empresas detentoras destes códigos/arquivos.

Espero ter ajudado.

Abraços,