# Existe plugin para upload de imagens para o Summernote?

Tags: upload, wysiwyg, summernote

Estou querendo usar Summernote e preciso fazer upload de imagens, mas não sei como fazer, existe algum plugin para isto (de preferencia gratuito ou com valor acessivel)?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, editei a pergunta.
Eu não consigo entender o critério de classificação de perguntas do site.
O site não poderia sugerir melhorar a pergunta antes de me negativar?
Aí derrepente me bloqueiam e não posso fazer mais nenhuma pergunta só porque eu não soube fazer UMA.

Comment: não foi um problema de critério, foi a maneira que você escreve que está confusa. Quem negativa são usuários, as pessoas podem negativar por qualquer motivo, geralmente são pessoas que não tem poder de fechar que negativam, o negativo não é pra dizer que a sua pergunta é inutil, é pra dizer *"óh tem uma coisa muito errada na sua pergunta"*, não entenda mal isto. A sua pergunta tem um monte de coisa escrita que não faz diferenteça pra quem vai responder, você se perde nas palavras e por isso fica dificil entender o que quer. Todavia eu entendi o problema e vou editar a pergunta...

Comment: Caraca, eu posso jurar que dias atrás eu quis usar o Summernote e não vi essa opção por isso vim aqui perguntar. O.o
Obrigado pelo ponto @GuilhermeNascimento.
Desculpe o transtorno. Acho que a confusão de palavras se deve ao fato de eu estar dormindo pouco mais de 4 horas por noite.

Comment: Eu sinceramente não sei qual é a melhor opção, atualmente estou salvando as imagens numa pasta no servidor e não no banco.
Mas se salvar no banco for uma boa opção então acredito que posso mudar isso.
De qualquer forma eu acredito que a questão está respondida, foi falta de atenção minha.

Comment: Neimeg desculpe a demora foi dificil fazer os exemplos, veja minha resposta e me diz se funciona assim pra ti.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O editor *SummerNote* já tem opção nativamente para converter a imagem em protocolo `data:` ([Data URI scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme)) assim a imagem vai "embarcada" com o texto:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#exemplo').summernote({ height: 300 });
});
```

```html
<!-- jquery, bootstrap -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- add summernote -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/summernote@0.8.18/dist/summernote.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/summernote@0.8.18/dist/summernote.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/summernote@0.8.18/dist/lang/summernote-ko-KR.min.js"></script>


<div id="exemplo"></div>
```

Então clique neste ícone e vai aparecer o pop-up:

[image: summernote image select]

### Upload para o servidor

No entanto é preferível não usar [Data URI scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) então existe um evento no *SummerNote* que permite fazer o upload usando Ajax, como o SummerNote é uma biblioteca JS que requer jQuery então vou mostrar um exemplo de upload com jQuery:

```
$('#summernote').summernote({
  callbacks: {
    onImageUpload: function(files) {
        var data = new FormData();
        data.append("file", files[0]);
        $.ajax({
            data: data,
            type: "POST",
            url: "upload.php", //arquivo de upload ou rota do laravel
            success: function(data) {
                if (data !== "") {
                  var img = new Image();
                  img.src = data;
                  $summernote.summernote('insertNode', img);
                }
            }
        });
    }
  }
});
```

Acredito que você use PHP (outra pergunta sua falava de PHP) então o upload.php deve ficar assim:

```
<?php
//Caminho absoluto do local que vai salvar as fotos
$pasta    = '/home/user/public_html/storage/upload/';

//URL que vai ser gerada
$pastaurl = 'http://meusite.com/storage/upload/';

$tmp_name = $_FILES['arquivo']['tmp_name'];

//Pega o mimetype
$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
$mime = finfo_file($finfo, $tmp_name);
finfo_close($finfo);

//Só permite upload de imagens
if (strpos($mime, 'image/') === 0) {

   //Gera um nome que não se repete para imagem e adiciona a extensão conforme o mimetype
   $file = time() . '.' . str_replace('image/', '', $mime);

   if (move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $pasta . '/' . $file)) {
       return $pastaurl . $file;
   }
}
```

### Documentação SummerNote:

- http://summernote.org/deep-dive/#callbacks

---

> Motivos para não usar [*Data URI scheme*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) em editores WYSIWYG
>
> ---
>
> Se o conteúdo do editor for salvo no banco de dados então realmente pode ser melhor usar "upload normal", outro problema do protocolo `data:` é a renderização, segue links que podem ajudar a explicar:
>
> - [Uma imagem base64 carrega mais rápido que uma url?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/95146/3635)
> - [É errado gravar byte de imagens no banco de dados?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/12687/3635)