# Manipular imagens em base64 com PHP

Tags: php, imagem, base64

Tenho algumas imagens codificadas em base64 no PHP. Preciso redimensionar essas imagens, definindo um tamanho máximo para elas antes de armazenar no banco.

Como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Existem sérios problemas ao gravar dados diretamente no banco, leia **[É errado gravar byte de imagens no banco de dados?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/12687/3635)** e **[Uma imagem base64 carrega mais rápido que uma url?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/95119/3635)**

Comment: Base64 basicamente serve para transmissão de dados em meios que tenham problemas com mais de 7 bits, é bom se certificar que não estão sendo usadas para armazenagem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tem que usar [`base64_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php), se for do banco pegue a variavel e faça isto:

```
$imageBin = base64_decode($row['imagem']); //Exemplo de variavel
```

Aqui um exemplo com arquivo:

```
<?php
//Caminho da imagem em base64
$path = '/home/amanda/imagem.jpg.bin';

/*Nota: em windows algo como c:/Users/amanda/imagem.jpg.bin*/

//Decodifica base64
$imageBin = base64_decode(file_get_contents($path));

//Grava o arquivo decodificado em um temporário
$tmpfname = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'base64_decode_');

$handle = fopen($tmpfname, 'w');
fwrite($handle, $imageBin);
fclose($handle);

//Limpa a variavel
$imageBin = null;

$img = null;

switch (variable) {
    case 'image/png':
        $img = imagecreatefrompng($tmpfname);
    break;
    case 'image/jpeg':
        $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($tmpfname);
    break;
    case 'image/gif':
        $img = imagecreatefromgif($tmpfname);
    break;
}

if (!$img) {
    //Resimensiona a imagem
    $originalWidth  = imageSX($img);
    $originalHeight = imageSY($img);

    if($originalWidth > $originalHeight)
    {
        $widthRatio = $newWidth;
        $heightRatio = $originalHeight*($newHeight / $originalWidth);
    }

    if($originalWidth < $originalHeight)
    {
        $widthRatio = $originalWidth*($newWidth / $originalHeight);
        $heightRatio = $newHeight;
    }

    if($originalWidth == $originalHeight)
    {
        $widthRatio = $newWidth;
        $heightRatio = $newHeight;
    }

    $resizedImg = imagecreatetruecolor($widthRatio, $heightRatio);

    imagecopyresampled($resizedImg, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $widthRatio, $heightRatio, $originalWidth, $originalHeight);

    switch (variable) {
        case 'image/png':
            imagepng($resizedImg, $tmpfname);
        break;
        case 'image/jpeg':
            imagejpeg($resizedImg, $tmpfname);
        break;
        case 'image/gif':
            imagegif($resizedImg, $tmpfname);
        break;
    }

    $img = $resizedImg = null;

    //Codifica o arquivo manipulado pra base64
    $imageBase64 = base64_encode(file_get_contents($tmpfname));

    //Sobreescreve a imagem em base64 original original
    file_put_contents($path, $imageBase64);

    $imageBase64 = null;
}

unlink($tmpfname); //Deleta o temporário
```

### Armazenar imagens ou não no banco de dados

Eu não recomendo fazer isto por 4 fatores:

1. Pode ser custoso ao banco e ao servidor, leia sobre isso em: **[É errado gravar byte de imagens no banco de dados?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/12687/3635)**
2. Você terá que decodificar cada imagem que irá pra exibição (apesar que é que é possível usar `data URI scheme`), o que consome muito do servidor
3. Mesmo que use `data URI scheme`, ainda sim a página irá ficar com muito conteúdo e irá demorar de carregar, leia mais sobre isto em: [**Uma imagem base64 carrega mais rápido que uma url?**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/95146/3635)
4. As imagens não poderão ter cache e cache é uma coisa muito boa pra carregar páginas visitadas mais rapidamente, veja uma boa maneira de usar cache para imagens e outros arquivos estáticos (acaso use apache): **[É possível usar if-modified-since com “304 not modified” sem PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/44141/3635)**

Comment: +1 E o mais importante: se for gravar no banco, não use Base64 :) Base64 em princípio é formato para transmissão de dados, não para armazenagem.

Comment: @Bacco concordo, mas acho que ela usou mesmo devido ao `data uri scheme`

Comment: Ai normalmente você usa o Base64 na hora de jogar na tela, e não no DB (a não ser que seja coisa bem minima, como ícones miúdos etc). No caso de um arquivo, tambem nao faz muito sentido, não vejo razão. Só está ocupando espaço (e processamento, neste caso especifico) à toa.

Comment: @Bacco exatamente, provavelmente ela chegou a esse uso pra tentar contornar outro problema, ou seja um problema pra tentar resolver outro :)