# O que é, e como funciona, uma ETag

Tags: http, http-headers

Estive fazendo solicitações por socket para meu servidor Apache com o intuito de criar um protótipo de *Framework*, e para cada arquivo diferente que era acessado, retornava uma *ETag* no cabeçalho.

Para que serve uma *ETag*? Como posso encontrar a *ETag* de um arquivo?

Comment: Socket ou websocket? ETag geralmente é somente para HTTP e não websockets (até aonde entendo) ... **sobre a sua duvida:** em uma curta resposta Etag é uma hash pra compara a alteração com o arquivo do servidor compando com o header `if-none-match`, todavia um exemplo de como usar Etag para arquivos estaticos e assim melhorar a performance do servidor: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/44141/3635 - PS: Se ninguem responder, amanhã eu tento descolar um tempo pra fazer uma resposta bem completa ;)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, estou utilizando socket normal mesmo

Answer (score 27, accepted):

De forma sucinta, [ETag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_ETag) é um mecanismo do HTTP para validação condicional de cache.

A ideia é servir conteúdo a ser cacheado com um identificador (geralmente um hash ou número de versão). O cliente então passa a usar esse identificador para perguntar ao servidor se o conteúdo mudou.

### Exemplo

O request:

```
GET /Trj17.png HTTP/1.1
Host: i.stack.imgur.com
```

Recebe a imagem com o header `ETag`:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK   
Content-Type: image/png
Content-Length: 61404
ETag: "a5ea8bbcc437de9787e9a87ef6ef690a"

corpo da imagem
```

O cliente então cacheia essa imagem. 
Quando o usuário requisitar a imagem novamente o cliente pode usar o identificador para "perguntar" ao servidor se a versão em cache ainda é válida:

```
GET /Trj17.png HTTP/1.1
Host: i.stack.imgur.com
If-None-Match: "a5ea8bbcc437de9787e9a87ef6ef690a"
```

Se a versão ainda for válida o servidor volta uma resposta com código 304, indicando que é seguro para o cliente usar a versão em cache:

```
HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
ETag: "a5ea8bbcc437de9787e9a87ef6ef690a"
```

No caso da imagem ter mudado o servidor responde com código 200, a nova versão da imagem e uma nova ETag.

Dessa forma, consideramos `ETag` um mecanismo de validação de cache baseado em conteúdo, em oposição ao par de cabeçalhos `Last-Modified` e `If-Modified-Since` que configuram um mecanismo de validação baseado em tempo.

Ambos os mecanismos de validação são complementares aos headers `Cache-Control` e `Expires` que basicamente dizem para o cliente se ele deve ou não cachear um recurso e até quando.

Answer (score 5):

**Em etag é basicamente um identificador para uma resposta a uma negociação de conteúdo. Se o conteúdo varia, a Etag varia, não necessariamente o endereço do recurso solicitado varia.**

Quando você faz uma requisição, ela pode variar a resposta de acordo com o contexto. Um exemplo simples seria se você faz uma requisição a um arquivo de texto, hora com suporte a Gzip e outra hora sem suporte, o arquivo requisitado, bem como a URL do recurso são os mesmos, porém a etag vai variar porque  a requisição variou.

Se você quiser ter uma definição mais formal, pode consultar as RFCs que implementam os protocolos:

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7232#section-2.3

Obs.: O exemplo foi tirado de lá (em inglês).

Se você pretende trabalhar diretamente com a implementação dos protocolos recomendo fortemente que inicie pelas RFC's, cada webserver implementa suporte a versões específicas dos protocolos, você pode verificar isso na documentação do próprio webserver. Sempre existe configurações adicionais no servidor para habilitar ou não um determinado recurso, então, 'sniffar'um conjunto de requisições não necessariamente te faz descobrir o suporte de determinado webserver, na verdade, te mostra o que a configuração atual da determinada instância do webserver suporta.

**Levando em conta que a etag de um determinado arquivo (que você não especificou o tipo) pode variar, você não vai encontrar uma etag para um arquivo, vai encontrar uma etag para um determinado contexto de requisição a um arquivo.**

Salvo engano, isso pode variar até mesmo dependendo do SO onde o webserver está instalado, mesmo para a mesma versão do Webserver, visto que os status de arquivo são retornados para o webserver pelo SO que só então retorna as mudanças para o request, veja a documentação do apache e procure por etag.

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/pt-br/

Como não sei o objetivo de seu framework, não posso sugerir nada em específico.