# Como exibir imagem sem uma extensão pelo link direto no navegador?

Tags: php, apache, htaccess

Exemplo - `http://meusite/imagem/001`

Resultado que não quero, desejo visualizar a imagem.

```
ÿØÿà�JFIF��H�H��ÿÛ�C�



ÿÛ�C        

ÿÀ�p�"�ÿÄ������������
    ÿÄ�7����!1A"Q2a¡Bq‘#3R$CbScðÿÄ�����������ÿÄ�)�������!1A"Q2a#BÿÚ���?�ù¶¨/d99ñI­”s/•[0ò¹mömç_'ŒkY™å?e¬I~FŽfŒ™Nk³©àévÊ=¿"øÝãøÏÎ×GUÅüQÛ¯Ñþ  ~9Æ§âÚ=/ƒÁ¦1ŽÒ93ÉÑŽs\Äÿ�Sðÿ�Œð?—†µ£³t×_Z0¹)AïG?zÙp‘Ée×ÛèÏ³ô™Uù6P–®–’65sµdÜž‰1p'‘%¨¶tœwÄ­Êš~
Ç   ð7œ c­¸ëµÃqÿ�œâ·XÊø‹œè=Z
```

Meu servidor tem o Apache será possível usar algo parecido com `AddType application/x-httpd- jpg`

Comment: Acho que você devia usar `image/jpeg`.

Answer (score 2):

Usando somente .htaccess talvez não seja possível, isso porque existem vários tipos de imagem e ficaria complicado adicionar o mime-type para cada uma, todavia você pode redirecionar para um php tratar isto, por exemplo:

Crie na pasta imagem um arquivo **.htaccess:** com este conteudo:

```apacheconf
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^ proxy_image.php?path=$0 [L]
```

Na mesma pasta crie um arquivo chamado `proxy_image.php` com o seguinte conteudo:

```php
<?php

function mimeType($file)
{
    $mimetype = false;

    if (class_exists('finfo')) {//PHP5.4+
        $finfo     = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
        $mimetype  = finfo_file($finfo, $file);
        finfo_close($finfo);
    } else if (function_exists('mime_content_type')) {//php5.3 ou inferiror
        $mimetype = mime_content_type($file);
    }

    return $mimetype;
}

if (empty($_GET['path'])) {
    echo 'Caminho invalido';
    exit;
}

$path = $_GET['path'];

$extensoes = array('jpeg', 'jpg', 'gif', 'png', 'ico', 'svg');

$fullPath = null;

//Busca pela primeiro arquivo que contiver a extensão (pode implementar glob também, é opicional)
foreach ($extensoes as $extensao) {
    if (is_file($path . '.' . $extensao)) {
        $fullPath = $path . '.' . $extensao;
        break;
    }
}

if ($fullPath) {
    //pega o mime-type do arquivo
    $mime = mimeType($fullPath);

    //Verifica se o mime-type é do tipo imagem
    if (strpos($mime, 'image/') === 0) {
        header('Content-Type: ' . $mime);

        readfile($path);
        exit;
    }
}

echo 'Isto não é uma imagem';
exit;
```

Depois basta navegar para algo como `http://localhost/images/foobar`, se existir uma imagem com este

Note que **é possível** implementar cache e usar Etag junto com este código acima, conforme usei neste exemplo da pergunta (não o da resposta):

- [É possível usar if-modified-since com “304 not modified” sem PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/44141/3635)

Answer (score 0):

> Esta resposta se deve ao fato de estar com a tag [PHP] na pergunta.

**Com PHP:**

Você pode inserir o `Header` no PHP:

```
header('Content-type: image/png');
```

O tipo do documento vai variar, por isso deve definir o `image/png` somente para imagens são de mesmo formato, normalmente é possível identificar o formato através de sua extensão, como `.png`.

Portanto poderia fazer algo como:

```
$tipo = [
'gif' => 'image/gif',
'png' => 'image/png',
'jpeg' => 'image/jpeg',
'jpg' => 'image/jpeg'
];

$nome = 'image.png';
$extensao = strtolower(substr(strrchr($nome,"."),1));

if( isset( $tipo[$extensao] )) {
   header('Content-type: '.$tipo[$file_extension]);
}

//... { Exibe um "echo" da imagem }
```

**Com Apache**

Você pode usar o `.htaccess` (ou altere no `httpd.conf` se estiver desligado) para forçar todos os arquivos terem um mesmo `content-type`.

```
<Location /imagem>
  ForceType image/jpeg
</Location>
```

Isso irá fazer com que todas as requisições para `/imagem` saiam com o `Content-type` previamente definido. ;)

Mais informações sobre o `ForceType` [pode ser vista aqui.](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_mime.html#forcetype)