# dúvida sobre desempenho

Tags: javascript, css

Estou montando uma pequena *Framework* de *design* CSS e JS para padronizar o sistema em que estou trabalhando.

Minha dúvida é como conseguir a melhor *performance*.

Já fiz várias coisas como habilitar o *cache*, organizar o código e etc...

Porém os navegadores em média fazem 6 requisição por vez ao servidor. Então pensei em colocar todo o CSS e JS em 2 arquivo. E depois fazer a versão minificada deles.

Assim o sistema faz apenas 2 requisição e carrega todo o CSS e JS para o cache.

Devo fazer assim, ou criar vários CSS e JS?

Comment: Oi Hugo, essa é uma questão bem interessante mas difícil de responder objetivamente... Penso que a melhor estrutura vai depender de vários fatores como quão frequentemente você vai atualizar o CSS / JS e se as áreas de atualização podem ser agrupadas. Temos também o HTTP/2 ganhando força. O HTTP/2 alivia bastante o custo de requests simultâneos; já existem inclusive [artigos recomendando o uso de arquivos separados](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/02/getting-ready-for-http2/#concatenating-css-and-javascript).

Comment: Minificar os recursos é uma boa idéia, e minimizar o número de *requests*  é certamente importante do ponto de vista de *performance*. O que você quer fazer é minimizar o número de requests -> maximizar o número de cache hits -> minimizar latência (e.g., com uma CDN) -> não servir JavaScript / CSS desnecessário (funções e estilos não usados na página atual). Veja que esses requisitos podem ser conflitantes e não há uma bala de prata melhor em todos os casos.

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly o JS e CSS não vão ser atualizado, vou carregar tudo no cache do navegador. Assim sempre que eu precisar de uma classe ou função vai estar no cache. Essa e minha ideia. Estou fazendo uns testes assim e o sistema esta carregando a página em torno de 2 segundos. Quando limpo o cache ele demora ate 4 positivá-los tem que carregar tudo de novo. O que vc acha?

Comment: Unir em um arquivo é apenas um pequena solução, veja se isto lhe ajuda: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/169657/3635, eu ainda preciso adicionar mais detalhes, mas assim que fizer lhe aviso.

Comment: Oi @HugoBorges, é complicado te dizer se isso "é bom" sem conhecer os específicos do site e do teste. Dito isso, o Developer Tools do Chrome pode te dar uma boa visão de como esse tempo está sendo gasto e se os arquivos JS e CSS estão impactando o tempo de carregamento. Geralmente imagens soltas são o principal gargalo, e de novo, existem soluções para agrupar imagens em *sprites* que entram no mesmo bonde das soluções de agrupamento acima. Boas práticas hoje que não necessariamente são/serão boas práticas no HTTP/2.

Answer (score 1):

**Unir e minify**

Extremamente recomendado unir os Css e JS o mínimo possível.
Os navegadores podem fazer de 6-8 requisições por segundo, quanto mais arquivos tiver, terá block no download.

Após unir o CSS's e JS's recomendo minificar ele, em sites como:

https://cssminifier.com/

https://jscompress.com/

OBS: unir o arquivo jquery com outros arquivos pode acontecer problemas, caso aconteça, coloque o jquery por CDN;

OBS²: Quando não puder unir arquivos pense no CDN, são sempre uma excelente forma de carregar arquivos.

Claro que existem ferramentas para automatizar esses processos.

**Compactar Gzip**

Se estiver utilizando o IIS
http://www.andrecarlucci.com/dev/como-habilitar-compressao-gzip-no-iis/
Caso contrário procure como "Habilitar Compactação de cabeçalho Gzip"

**Tamanho das imagens.**

Verifique sempre o tamanho das imagens, normalmente elas podem ser o grande vilão. Já vi sites com imagens na casa dos 900kb.

**Utilize uma ferramenta de testes**
Por fim, a melhor coisa é utilizar alguma ferramenta para testar o desempenho e verificar se ouve melhoras e o que falta fazer, o próprio Chrome existe ferramentas ótimas.
Caso queira recomendo uma simples e eficaz
https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/