# Site não abre no IOS,

Tags: redirecionamento

Galera estou com o seguinte problema, o site 
https://aramaquinas.com.br/ não abre no safari no IOS ele abre normalmente no windows, mas no iphone não abre, alguem ja passou por isso?

o que pode ocasionar essa falha no carregamento que utiliza um SO especifico? achei que era algum problema no DNS, ou no certficiado SSL, porem ambos apresentam-se normais

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Existem 3 recursos que não estão sendo carregados, todos com  404 (Not Found):

```
https://aramaquinas.com.br/image/catalog/ban1xx.jpg
https://aramaquinas.com.br/image/catalog/ban2x.jpg
https://aramaquinas.com.br/image/catalog/sub2x.jpg
```

Não posso afirmar que eles esteja conflitando com o HTTPS quando caem em 404, mas talvez seja algo relacionado que só ocorra em iOS.

### Outras otimizações a considerar

O seu site esta muito mal otimizado pra mobile, desculpe a sinceridade, mas **não adianta** um site ser responsivo e você carregar umas 5 fontes diferentes, diferentes `.css` e `.js` **não** minificados (e não unificados) e carregar várias imagens.

Não é que o site não abre, é que simplesmente pro tanto de memória que um celular tem ele nunca vai conseguir carregar, ele fica carregando muito tempo, se olhar no topo o load nunca terminar.

Eu respondi algo bem semelhante em: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/169657/3635

Há muito o que melhorar em seu site:

- Reduza o numero de imagens, de preferencia tente técnica como CSS Sprite
- Unificar os principais `.js` e `.css` em um único arquivo (são aqueles .css e .js que vão em todas páginas), se for asp.net-mvc pode usar o https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization/
- Comprima os .js e .css (creio que o Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization já faça isso)
- Use HTTP compactado pra arquivos "estáticos" com js e css
- Procure usa apenas uma WebFont, no máximo duas
- Não carregar arquivos em páginas que não serão usadas, como por exemplo, eu tenho certeza que você não usa estes scripts em todas páginas:

  ```
  <!-- Megnor www.templatemela.com - Start -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="catalog/view/javascript/megnor/custom.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="catalog/view/javascript/megnor/jstree.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="catalog/view/javascript/megnor/carousel.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="catalog/view/javascript/megnor/megnor.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="catalog/view/javascript/megnor/jquery.custom.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="catalog/view/javascript/megnor/jquery.formalize.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="catalog/view/javascript/lightbox/lightbox-2.6.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="catalog/view/javascript/megnor/tabs.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="catalog/view/javascript/megnor/jquery.elevatezoom.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="catalog/view/javascript/megnor/bootstrap-notify.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="catalog/view/javascript/megnor/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="catalog/view/javascript/megnor/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="catalog/view/javascript/megnor/doubletaptogo.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="catalog/view/javascript/jquery/magnific/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Megnor www.templatemela.com - End -->
  ```

  Isso deve estar acabando com a performance do Safari, fazendo com que ele nem consiga carregar a página

---

### Leia também sobre bloqueio de renderização

O bloqueio de renderização ocorre quando esta ocorre o download de um recurso externo, como um CSS ou um JavaScript e o navegador não renderiza nenhum conteúdo processado até que este download e processamento tenha sido concluído, em um exemplo prático:

```
<link href="bar.css">
<script src="foo.js"></script>

<div>foo</div>
```

O div só vai renderizar no browser quando bar.css e foo.js carregarem, para evitar este tipo de bloqueio veja estas sugestões:

- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/115240/3635

---

### Como saber se estou indo no caminho certo?

Não há muito como saber se o caminho para otimização que você esta tentando é o "melhor", mas existe uma ferramenta online que pode ajudar um pouco:

- https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?hl=pt-br

Ele vai te dar um resultado de score da sua página:

[image: pagespeed]

Comment: Outra coisa: imagina o tando de Gigabyte que uma pessoa iria gastar no seu plano de dados de celular só pra abrir a página inicial.

Comment: @Dvdsamm sim, uma das principais motivações da existencia do pagespeed é justamente essa, proporcionar uma boa UserExperience, ou seja UX pode ser qualquer coisa, vai além de visual/grafico, o UX se refere a experiencia, se a página carrega rapido será uma boa experiencia, se a página consome pouco da franquia, será outra otima experiencia e assim por diante.

Comment: É, acho que depois da "explosão" de dispositivos móveis, encher o site de recursos pesados visando a "beleza estética" ficou talvez em último plano. Um site não precisa ser pesado para ser bonito, navegável e com recursos que atendam bem ao seu propósito.

Comment: @Dvdsamm a maioria das pessoas não entendem o que são recursos, mesmo em Desktop, muitos apps são pesados porque os programadores são inexperientes, eles estão preocupados em entregar algo funcionando, eles não entendem de performance, não entendem do básico que é memória e CPU e muito menos de "leitura de disco" (outro problema que pode afetar os computadores). Resumindo: isso não é um problema exclusivo Web, atinge todos ambientes, por culpa de programadores que não entendem ou que não se preocupam.

Comment: apsesar do overload de recursos, acredito que essa não é a causa do não acarregamento da pagina, pois o site abre normalmente no safari no macbook, abre no windows e no android, a unico problema é que não abre no safari do iphone, eu sei que a estrutura do site esta desorganizada, acredito que a pessoa que desenvolveou não possua muitos conhecimentos tecnicos

Comment: @HebertdeLima iPhones tem bem menos memoria que celulares android, enquanto um androids decentes tem 2gb ou mais os iPhones de 512mb a 1gb, um computador Mac tem de 4GB a 16gb (os mais "comuns").

Comment: o pagespeed deu 75? esta melhor que o da amazon e do ebay, e de outras ecommerces grandes, conheço as boas praticas mas não sou o desenvolvedor da loja, estou apenas tentando ajudar um colega =)

Comment: @HebertdeLima amazon e ebay tem versões mobile e não são responsivos, ou seja são sites diferentes para mobile e desktop. Outra coisa, o Score é só uma margem, a questão é **totalmente relativa**, como eu disse na resposta "o google pagespeed pode ajudar **um pouco**": *Não há muito como saber se o caminho para otimização que você esta tentando é o "melhor", mas existe uma ferramenta online que pode ajudar um pouco*

Comment: estou em duvida entre essas duas possibilidades: window.history.back();
javascript:history.go(-1) porem não sei como rastrear

Comment: outro ponto, o erro só ocorre sobre o protocolo HTTPS se eu mudo para HTTP ele carrega normal, eu entendo seu ponto sobre otmização mas realmente acredito que não é a causa do problema

Comment: @HebertdeLima entendo, vou dar uma olhada nisto.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66597/discussion-between-hebert-de-lima-and-guilherme-nascimento).

Comment: A resposta possui mérito, porém não responde a pergunta do OP: *"[O] que pode ocasionar essa falha no carregamento que utiliza um SO especifico?"* Mesmo não otimizado o site abre propriamente em dispositivos Android.

Comment: @OnoSendai a pergunta era bem vaga, e levei em consideração que geralmente androids tem mais bem mais memória, sei que a arquitetura iOS e Android são diferentes e exigem quantidades diferente, geralmente o iOS exigindo menos, todavia a resposta se baseou no que eu tinha de informação até o momento e não nas informações que eu obtive depois (ver comentários anteriores).

Comment: @HebertdeLima o máximo que encontrei de possivel falha foram 3 resources invalidos (404), tente corrigir eles e atualizar a página no Safari iOS depois.